# Identify two songs from Innova Irish Dance Company at Britain's Got Talent (2014)

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

Can please someone identify the two instrumental parts of the mix of songs in this [Innova Irish Dance Company are the belles of BGT | Britain's Got Talent 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeQJ25XtM-Y). That should be semi-final performance of the Innova Irish Dance Company.

The parts with singing I could find by lyrics, however the instrumental parts are a bit tricky. Those instrumental parts starts at [0:51](https://youtu.be/jeQJ25XtM-Y?t=51) and [1:29](https://youtu.be/jeQJ25XtM-Y?t=89).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is **DVBBS & Borgeous**' [*Tsunami*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0ewsr3s7yM).

The second is **Calvin Harris**' [*Summer*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebXbLfLACGM).